# offset not work in query in tableadapter in visual studio

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I create dataset in my asp.net website and add query to tableadapters.
Now I want to skip one row from a table and take 4 next rows from table.
I search for it and get this code:

```
DECLARE @N INT = 5 --Any random number

SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RoNum
              , ID --Add any fields needed here (or replace ID by *)
        FROM TABLE_NAME
) AS tbl 
WHERE @N < RoNum
ORDER BY tbl.ID
```

but not works.
please help me to skip 1 and take 4 rows from it.
Thank you

and when I use offset got this error:
[my eroro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKjAc.png)

and I got this error too:
[my next error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNKGH.png)

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OFFSET` to skip the first row, and `FETCH NEXT` to specify the number of rows fo fetch:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME

WHERE col1 = value    -- optional WHERE clause with condition(s)

ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I Got this error when use this code : Unable to parse query text.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: I use visaual studio 2015 and database is on server using sqlserver 2016

Comment: I attached the photo to question

Comment: @YogeshSharma, thanks for the edit. (That ROWS keyword in the OFFSET clause is optional according to the ANSI SQL standard.)

Comment: <result offset clause> ::=
OFFSET <offset row count> { ROW | ROWS }

Comment: <fetch first clause> ::=
FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ <fetch first quantity> ] { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES }

Comment: @jarlh. .  Yes, but op is running it `VS` GUI.

Comment: so thanks, Now this code is working but I want to add "where" to this query .
where should I put "where" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need `OFFSET` clause :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE_NAME t
ORDER BY ID 
OFFSET 1 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
```

I suspect you need `newid()` based on your description, if so then you can do :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE_NAME t
ORDER BY newid() 
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;
```

By this way you will get random 4 rows.

**EDIT :** Other way you can use `row_number()` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS seq
      FROM TABLE_NAME t
     ) AS tbl 
WHERE seq > 1 AND seq <= @N
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: I Got this error when use this code : Unable to parse query text.

Comment: @siyavash1989. . .  You didn't mentioned `order by` clause with the query.

Comment: I mentioned order by and yet I got error. I attached the photo to question

Comment: @siyavash1989. . . `OFFSET` has typo.

Comment: which part has typo?

Comment: where should I put "where" clause?

Comment: @siyavash1989. . . simply after `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks dude  @}--